# Uma dúvida de PHP

Tags: php

Olá, estou com uma dúvida de como fazer uma inserção num banco de dados.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 18rem;\">";
            //echo "<img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"...\" alt=\"Card image cap\">";
        echo '<img class=\"card-img-top\" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['imagem']) .'"/>';
        echo "<div class=\"card-body\">";
        echo "<h5 class=\"card-title\">Card title</h5>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<ul class=\"list-group list-group-flush\">";
        echo "<li name=\"prod\"class=\"list-group-item\">".$row['id_Produto']."</li>";
        echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\">".$row['nome']."</li>";
        echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\">Vestibulum at eros</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "<div class=\"card-body\">";
        echo "<a href = \"adicionarCarrinho.php\" method = \"post\"class=\"card-link\">Adicionar ao carrinho</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
```

Oq estou tentando fazer é quando o usuário clicar no botao `echo "<a href = \"adicionarCarrinho.php\" method = \"post\"class=\"card-link\">Adicionar ao carrinho</a>";` um arquivo php pegue o `.$row['id_Produto'].` e adicione em uma tabela pedido onde contem id_pedido e uma chave estrangeira produto_id. No caso teriam vários produtos e um usuário poderia adicionar vários ao pedido.

Isso tudo só pode ser feito em php(trabalho da faculdade)
Obrigado

Comment: Acredito que o melhor caminho seja utilizando ajax.

Comment: Eu não posso, é obrigatório somente PHP

Comment: então crie um formulário só com o botão de subtmit em cada card do produto. e toda vez que submitar adiciona ao carrinho e redireciona pra essa mesma página.

Comment: e um type hidden com o id do produto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo de como eu faria, talvez não seja a resposta ideal para o seu caso:
- Fiz uma array `$row`, simulando os dados vindos do banco, mas que pode ser substituído e adequado a cada caso.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $row = [['id_produto' => 1], ['id_produto' => 2], ['id_produto' => 3], ['id_produto' => 3], ['id_produto' => 3], ['id_produto' => 3], ['id_produto' => 3], ['id_produto' => 3], ['id_produto' => 3], ['id_produto' => 3]];
    $qtdProdutos = 10;
    for ($i=0; $i <= ($qtdProdutos-1); $i++):?>
        <div class="card">
            <form action="adicionarcarrinho.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_produto" value="<?= $row[$i]['id_produto']?>">
                <input type="submit" value="Adicionar ao Carrinho">
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me ajudou cara, utilizando "value" eu consegui ao menos imprimir o valor em outra página

Comment: isso, agora é só cadastrar o id do produto na tabela de pedidos, uma sugestão é caso tenha usuários, cadastrar também o id do usuário. aí vc tira 10

Comment: Isso eu não estou conseguindo, não está dando erro mas não insere no banco

Comment: descobri faltou o $stmt->execute();

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar